# Use of zip() throws "Shape of passed values is (x,y), indices imply (w,z)" on DataFrames with mixed types

Tags: python, pandas

*** EDITED EDITED EDITED ***

I am wrestling with this issue for quite some time and **while the plain vanilla case works fine, I keep getting this error on a DataFrame with mixed types**.

My objective is to add two new, calculated columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({'one' : pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4]),
                   'two' : pd.Series([20, 30, 40, 50]),
                   'zree': pd.Series([dt.datetime(2016, 7, x) for x in range(1, 5)])})

df['sum'], df['prod'] = zip(*df.apply(lambda row: (row.one + row.two,
                                                   row.one * row.two), axis=1))


...
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 2), indices imply (4, 3)
```

The **error disappears when I remove column 'zree' containing datetime or change type to int**.

Is there any workaround?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:49:46) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

pd.__version__
'0.18.1'
```

Comment: I edited the question after stepping through Pandas code and realising that this has nothing to do with pickling but rather than mixed types of columns.
So, here is a reproducible example.  
My passionate but relatively short affair with Python does not let me fully understand the intricacies of Pandas yet.

Comment: Apply is also called [flexible apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply) in the docs. Based on the input, pandas is doing some smart things to change the output to something more *useful*. For example a dict may turn into a dataframe. My best guess is that when you have all numeric columns, it doesn't do that transformation but when you have mixed type (or datetime specifically) it changes the type of the output. In this [example](http://i.imgur.com/4ZMAfS7.png) the result is broadcasted for the first df but not for the second - it stays as a tuple.

Comment: The relevant part from the docs: "apply can act as a reducer, transformer, or filter function, depending on exactly what is passed to apply. So depending on the path taken, and exactly what you are grouping. Thus the grouped columns(s) may be included in the output as well as set the indices."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was intrigued by your issue with mixed types and did some digging in `DataFrame`'s source code. Apparently when your `DataFrame` is mixed type (i.e. `df._is_mixed_type` is `True`), a different function is applied than when it is homogeneous.

When you call `apply` on a mixed-type DataFrame, it calls `DataFrame._apply_standard` (at least in your case) which then returns `DataFrame(data=results, index=index)`. `results` is a dict built from the output of your function `{0: (21, 20), 1: (32, 60), 2: (43, 120), 3: (54, 200)}` and `index` is `Index(['one', 'two', 'zree'])` (i.e. the columns of your `DataFrame`). As you can see, there is a discrepancy between the size of your index (3) and that of the results (2 per column) which don't match.

To avoid this, you need to return a `Series` in your function:

```
df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series((row.one + row.two, row.one * row.two)), axis=1)
```

In this case, df's index is used in the resulted `DataFrame` instead of the columns as index:

```
In [83]  df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series((row.one + row.two, row.one * row.two)), axis=1)
Out[83]  
    0    1
0  21   20
1  32   60
2  43  120
3  54  200
```

To get the desired result from your original post, you can do this:

```
In [90]  zip(*df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series((row.one + row.two,
                                               row.one * row.two)), axis=1).values)
Out[90]  [(21, 32, 43, 54), (20, 60, 120, 200)]
```

In the case of a same-type `DataFrame`, `DataFrame._apply_raw` is called which in your case returns a `Series` since the output of your function is a list (1-dimension).

I hope this clears things up a bit, you can do some debugging if you need to find out more. I tested with pandas version 0.18.1.

Comment: Thanks a million for the explanation.  
I don't want to drag this but still no joy.

Since I deal with millions of rows in my df, I would like to avoid traversing the dataset multiple times.
This is why I use zip() to return several columns at a time, which does not seem to make sense now.  
    df['sum'], df['prod'] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series((row.one + row.two, row.one * row.two)), axis=1)  
I get  
        one two zree     sum prod  
    0 1.0 20 2016-07-01 0 1  
    1 2.0 30 2016-07-02 0 1  
    2 3.0 40 2016-07-03 0 1  
    3 4.0 50 2016-07-04 0 1

Comment: @IrekRybark I updated my answer with an example which yields the same output as desired in your question. Calling `.values` on the resulting DataFrame returns a 2-d array with the function results in each row (which can be unpacked and used with `zip`).

Comment: @IrekRybark Is it possible for you to share the actual operation (assuming this is just an example) maybe we can work out a vectorized solution?

Comment: @sirfz: .values... that works. Learned something again.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `df.apply` needs to return something for the third column too and your `lambda` is returning two values for each row.
So just select your first two columns like this to get a 4x2 DataFrame for your `apply`:

`df['sum'], df['prod'] = zip(*df[['one', 'two']].apply(lambda row: (row.one + row.two, row.one * row.two), axis=1))`

Comment: Kaveh, thanks for the suggestion.  As a workaround, it works and I will take it!
However, it does not explain why changing type of 'zree' column to int makes my code work.